# Can you use a CTE in a CASE expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.1.

I tried this query:

```
with

parent_nodes as
(select p from bst where p is not null)

select n,
case 
when p is null then 'Root'
when n not in parent_nodes then 'Leaf' 
else 'Inner'
end node
from bst;
```

This fails with this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "parent_nodes"
LINE 9: when n not in parent_nodes then 'Leaf'
```

If I replace CTE `parent_nodes` with a subquery i.e.

```
when n not in (select p from bst where p is not null) then 'Leaf'
```

it works.  Is it not possible to use a CTE in a CASE expression?

Comment: `parent_nodes` is a table expression and must be used the same way as a table. `x IN table` is not a correct syntax.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine a CTE as being a view that is defined only for a single query. Similar to a view, it is used like a table, that is, in the `FROM` clause of a (sub)query.

That means that you have to write

```
... IN (SELECT ... FROM cte)
```

even if the CTE has only a single column and there would be no ambiguity.